# Embedding local camera feed in Next.js application results in failed streaming

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stream

I'm trying to embed a local camera feed (http://192.168.1.100:81/stream) inside my Next.js application, but the streaming is not working as expected. When I reload the page, the video player keeps loading for a few seconds and then stops without streaming.

I have tried using the video tag to display the stream, but that did not work.
Here is my code:

```
<video autoPlay muted loop>
  <source src='http://192.168.1.100:81/stream' />
</video>
```

I have made sure that the camera feed is accessible by opening the URL http://192.168.1.100:81/stream in my browser and in a plain html file, and it is working correctly.

I have also looked into the Network section and here's what I got

[image]

Can anyone help me with this issue? Why is the local camera feed not streaming inside my Next.js application?